# override initComponent() method

Tags: extjs4, extjs-mvc

I want to override initComponent( ) method of Ext.grid.column.Column class. But some how it executes all those lines. Basically I want to remove listeners from element and wants to assign it to other Element.

```
Ext.override(Ext.grid.column.Column, 
{     
    initComponent: function(){
         .
         .  //All lines are as it is till me.callParents(); 
         .
         .
         .
         .
         .
         .
         .
         // Initialize as a HeaderContainer
         me.callParent(arguments);

        me.on({      <<<------------------------------Do not need these.
            element:  'el',
            click:    me.onElClick,
            dblclick: me.onElDblClick,
            scope:    me
        });
        me.on({      <<<------------------------------Do not need these.
            element:    'titleEl',
            mouseenter: me.onTitleMouseOver,
            mouseleave: me.onTitleMouseOut,
            scope:      me
        });

    }

}
```

I do not want to attach listeners to "el" and "titleEl"  so i remove those lines. But some how it still add listeners.
I also write me.un() in AfterRender function. even tho it adds listener to "El" and "titleEl"

can anybody please guide me where i am wrong?????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `Ext.override`, use `Ext.define` to create a sub-class. When you redefine the `initComponent` method, you can use `this.superclass.superclass.initComponent.call` to skip over `Ext.grid.column.Column#initComponent`.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.grid.column.Column', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.column.Column',
    alias:  'widget.mycolumn',

    initComponent: function(){
        // Pre-initComponent from column class here

        // Ext.grid.header.Container#initComponent
        this.superclass.superclass.initComponent.call(this);

        // Do optional stuff here
    }
});
```

Then when you create your new columns, use `xtype: 'mycolumn'` to use your own implementation while still being able to use regular columns as needed.